# Review the code to read external adc values

Tags: c, embedded, avr, avr-gcc

I have started newly working with AVR microcontroller.I am using ATmega32-A microcontroller. I have connected one external ADC(AD7798). I want read external ADC values using SPI communication.I have tried so much but i am not able to get ADC values. My project is I have to generate waveform using micro controller with programmable waveform generator. I am successfully doing this and giving this signal to sensor. I want read sensor output from ADC. I have attached simple circuit diagram below. I wrote code like this

```
// I have initialized PORTB like this

PORTB=0x00;
DDRB=0xBF;

// SPI initialisation
// SPI clock rate fck/16
// SPI master
// SPI MSB first
// SPI CPOL = 1, CPHA = 1

SPCR=0x5D;
PORTB.3 = 1; 

void main (void){

 printf("adc value :%x\n",ReadAd());

}
```

I wrote all function in another file

I have read data sheet hundreds of times but still I am able to read ADC value. I am confusing what mistakes I am doing. I have checked each and every pin and I have checked ADC input pin using Oscilloscope, i am getting 0.6V input signal. Please help me to solve this problem. Tommarow is the deadline for this project. Please any one help me to read ADC values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: +1 for quality circuit diagram

Comment: Is that a photo of a whiteboard drawing?  If so, what tool(s) did you use to clean it up?

Comment: @Michael Burr,No it is hand drawn on a paper and the PDF image is scanned copy of that paper.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't pinpoint the problem, but here are some things I noticed that may help:

- Look into what the waveform generator chip is doing with the SDATA line.  It needs to be high-impedance when you're using the ADC since they share the same bus line (MOSI).  Make sure the chip isn't always driving the bus line, or your ADC comms will never work.
- There are no pull-up resistors on your chip select lines, which could cause the ADC to go into unusual states while the uC is powering up, etc.  You may want to enable internal pull-ups on portb 3 and 4, using this info from the atmega32 datasheet (page 50):

> "If PORTxn is written logic one when the pin is configured as an input pin, the pull-up >resistor is activated"

- Make sure your SPI clock polarity and phase match the communication protocol of the ADC, and that the ADC supports the 8-bit-at-a-time communication of a hardware SPI
- Your ChipSelectAD function has a line that may be unnecessary, though maybe I just don't know the purpose of reading a pin when the bit is set as an output

  > "while(PINB.3);  //Wait for chip select pin"
- Are the pins of your ADC wired correctly?  The diagram shows nothing for the power or reference voltage connections.
- Possibly slow down your SPI SCLK frequency until you're sure things work, though it looks like the ADC can handle pretty high input clock speeds.
- Make sure that your left shift while adc reading is happening on a 16-bit value... it looks like the 8-bit character result of the SPI read is actually getting shifted 8 times, making it zero unless the compiler automatically upcast the type.